# Merge more than one excel files into one excel file using Apache POI Java

Tags: java, excel, merge, apache-poi, bulkinsert

I am having 100 excel files and I want to merge all of them into one excel file. Here in my example I am having 2 excel files and I want to merge them into one. I can't do it. I am using Apache POI API.
In one excel workbook there can be more than one sheets also so I want to iterate through sheets of each workbook also.
I tried and researched but I got this link and it's not working for me
[https://dev.to/eiceblue/merge-excel-files-in-java-2lo2#:~:text=A%20quick%20way%20to%20merge,data%20table%20into%20another%20worksheet](https://dev.to/eiceblue/merge-excel-files-in-java-2lo2#:%7E:text=A%20quick%20way%20to%20merge,data%20table%20into%20another%20worksheet).

Please help me out here.

```
package com.cas.ExcelTest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Combine {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        String[] files = new String[] {"Test2.xlsx","Test3.xlsx"};
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();     
        try {
            for (int f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {    
                String file = files[f];
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                XSSFWorkbook tempWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                          
                int numOfSheets = tempWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();
                    
                for (int i = 0; i < numOfSheets; i++) {
                    XSSFSheet tempSheet = tempWorkbook.getSheetAt(i);
                    String newSheetName = ""+f+""+tempSheet.getSheetName();
                    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(newSheetName);
                    Iterator<Row> itRow = tempSheet.rowIterator();
                
                    while(itRow.hasNext()) {
                        Row tempRow = itRow.next();
                        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(tempRow.getRowNum());
                        Iterator<Cell> itCell = tempRow.cellIterator();
                    
                        while(itCell.hasNext()) {
                            Cell tempCell = itCell.next();
                            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(tempCell.getColumnIndex());
                        
                        switch (tempCell.getCellType()) {
                        case NUMERIC:
                            cell.setCellValue(tempCell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case STRING:
                            cell.setCellValue(tempCell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        case BLANK:
                            break;
                        case BOOLEAN:
                            break;
                        case ERROR:
                            break;
                        case FORMULA:
                            cell.setCellValue(tempCell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case _NONE:
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                        }       
                    }       
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file");
            ex1.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("result.xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

> My Excel files:

[Test2.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ye1q.png)

[Test3.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6QYn.png)

Here some columns are extra in Test3.xlsx and in both files as you can see in the heading row its all string but after that it has numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an approximation of the code you need, format it, extract functionalities to methods and check the naming of sheets.

```
String[] files = new String[] {"Test2.xlsx","Test3.xlsx"};
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = createSheetWithHeader(workbook);
    
try {
    for (int f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
        String file = files[f];
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook tempWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            
        int numOfSheets = tempWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets();
            
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSheets; i++) {
            XSSFSheet tempSheet = tempWorkbook.getSheetAt(i);
                
            int indexLastDataInserted = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int firstDataRow = getFirstDataRow(tempSheet);
                                
            Iterator<Row> itRow = tempSheet.rowIterator();
            
            while(itRow.hasNext()) {
                Row tempRow = itRow.next();
                
                if (tempRow.getRowNum() >= firstDataRow) {
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(indexLastDataInserted + 1);
                    
                    Iterator<Cell> itCell = tempRow.cellIterator();
                    
                    while(itCell.hasNext()) {
                        Cell tempCell = itCell.next();
                        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(tempCell.getColumnIndex());
                        //At this point you will have to set the value of the cell depending on the type of data it is
                        switch (tempCell.getCellType()) {
                            case NUMERIC:
                                cell.setCellValue(tempCell.getNumericCellValue());
                                break;
                            case STRING:
                                cell.setCellValue(tempCell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            /**
                             * Add your other types, here is your problem!!!!!
                             */
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    } 
}catch (IOException ex1) {
    System.out.println("Error reading file");
    ex1.printStackTrace();
}
    
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("result.xlsx")) {
    workbook.write(outputStream);
}
```

Function to get the first data row (necessary to avoid having to enter by hand where the header of each excel ends):

```
/**
 * If the tab has a filter, it returns the row index of the filter + 1, otherwise it returns 0
 * @param tempSheet
 * @return index of first data row
 */
public static Integer getFirstDataRow(XSSFSheet tempSheet) {
    Integer result = 0;
    Boolean isAutoFilter = tempSheet.getCTWorksheet().isSetAutoFilter();
    
    if (isAutoFilter) {
        String autoFilterRef = tempSheet.getCTWorksheet().getAutoFilter().getRef();
        
        result = new CellReference(autoFilterRef.substring(0, autoFilterRef.indexOf(":"))).getRow() + 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Create the sheet with header in the method:

```
public static XSSFSheet createSheetWithHeader(XSSFWorkbook workbook){
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("NEW_SHEET_NAME");

    //Implement the header
    [...]

    return sheet;
}
```

Comment: Here in both of my files some columns are same and some are different but in this while loop when I set cell values then I have done it according to test2.xlsx but it didn't work for other file as some of its column are different So whats the solution here?  @JLazar0

Comment: I do not understand the problem very well, this is a piece of conceptual code for you to complete, I think problems can give you where the comment is, that if the data type is not text it gives an error, but as I indicate you should complete it in that point.

The version of POI used is 4.1.0, can you attach an example of the excels that fail you or the log trace to see if it is due to the type of data?

Comment: Have a look at my question now I have added my excel files @JLazar0

Comment: Ok, what you need is to gather all the data that is below the filters in a single table?

Comment: Yeah but I also wan the heading of all

Comment: I'm testing with filter and merged cells and I don't get an error, could you provide the error trace?

Comment: I can't get it what to write in while loop of cells iteration as in like cell.setCellValue(....)?
Can you edit your answer it would be more beneficial for me.

Comment: I have edited the code so that it fills only one sheet of the excel result, identifies the first row of data and concatenating them all.

It would be necessary to implement the createHeader method and the switch depending on the cell type

Comment: I did it and it worked properly now I have one doubt left it's that I have result.xlsx which has 2 sheets but I want all data in 1 sheet so how to do that?

Comment: You're not making it easy for me xD.

In the code snippet that I put for you, the createSheet method is only called once, could it be that you are creating a sheet in the method where you create the header?

I edit the code with the modification.